# Django. how to assign the right variable to pre populating the form

Tags: python, django, forms, variable-assignment

I am trying to pre populate the form to the edit entry, but I am having a problem to assign the right variable.

I did a test using just a text to populate it, and it works. But could somebody give a hint in how to do  it retrieving the content and title from util.save_entry(title,content).

My test:

```
def edit_entry(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = EditEntryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
        content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
        util.save_entry(title,content)
    args = {'form':form, 'content':content}
    return render (request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "name": title,
            "content": content
        }, args)

   
if request.method == "GET":
   
    util.save_entry(title,content)
    form = EditEntryForm(initial={'title': title, 'content': content})
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form": EditEntryForm(initial={'title': title, 'content': content})
        
    })
```

Comment: How do you setup the `EditEntryForm`?

Comment: class EditEntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title")
    content = forms.CharField(label="Content")

Comment: I see you are saving the data (I guess in database) in `POST` . Therefore you need to retrieve them (in `GET` ), from where you are saving them. `util.save_entry` is not from django, so I guess it is something custom.

Comment: This is the question, I do not know how to retrieve them in GET :(. I am reading the documentation, but so many days with this problem, maybe my brain is blocked.I tried so many ways, I suppose it is simple, but I am starting in django and this is being very confusing to me.

Comment: How is your `util.save_entry` function looked like?

Comment: filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))

Comment: I wrote a code to create a new page using util.save_entry, it works fine, but my problem is to pre populate this 'edit entry' page.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using CBV? [UpdtateView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) handles the retriving of the data for a particular object (in this case, the one you're updating/editing). However, in both cases (function views or class views) you have to pass some idetifier (I recomend using PK or slug) for retriving that object, you do this through the URL, which might be the thing you're missing. As I told you, UpdateView already handles that, but for your case using function views:

For best practices, and in this case, for pourposes, add `self`, `request`, `*args` and `**kwargs` as parameters for your `edit_entry` function, then you can get the identifier of the object you want to edit by adding at the beginning of your function the following code:

```
identifier=request.kwargs['identifier']
```

So in your `urls.py` you should have:

```
path('url/to/edit/<identifier>', ...)
```

Then, below the `identifier` definition in `edit_entry`, define a variable to retrive the specific object you want to edit

```
object=MyModel.objects.get(identifier=identifier)
```

Pass the object through your context, just as you're doing with the form and in template:

```
<input type="your-field-type" class="some-class" name="field" id="id_field" value="{{object.field}}">
```

That should do the work since your `POST` method is already working.
Sorry if the answer was a little bit extensive.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your time. I did not learn to work with model yet. I need to study your answer, but for sure it will help in some way.